# How to understand this rust closure practice problem?

Tags: rust

Consider the following API:

```
pub struct Analyzer<F> {
    postprocess: F
}
impl<F: ___(i32) -> i32> Analyzer<F> {
    fn process(&self, n: i32) -> i32 { /* .. */ }
    pub fn pipeline(&self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        let n = self.process(n);
        (self.postprocess)(n)
    }
}
```

Which of the following function traits is most appropriate to fill in the blank?

1. `FnOnce`
2. `FnMut`
3. `Fn`

Supplied Answer:

> `pipeline` could be called multiple times, so `FnOnce` is not appropriate. `pipeline` takes an immutable reference to `self`, if `f` were `FnMut`, it could not be called within `pipeline`. Therefore `Fn` is most appropriate here.

Question: We don't know how many times `pipeline` will be called and it feels weird that the compiler make decisions based on this kind of assumptions. I think rust reach this conclusion through other mechanism and the explanation just happen to match it with come up cases.

Comment: It is not weird, `Fn`, `FnOnce` and `FnMut` point the capability of the closure that this API requires but I didn't really get what is the question here?

Comment: Another way of expressing the same explanation is that calling an `FnOnce` closure _moves_ the closure into the call. Since we only have a shared reference to `self`, we can't move the closure out of the `Analyzer` struct.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the `call*()` methods in the different `Fn*` traits in the Rust documentation. The `self` parameter in these methods is the closure itself. You'll see that `self` is passed either by shared reference, mutable reference or value depending on the type of the closure.

Comment: Signature of `pipeline` forces you to choose which Fn trait to choose. If it takes `&self` you can only choose `Fn`. If it takes `&mut self` you can choose `Fn` and `FnMut`. And if it takes `self`, you can use any of `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` (however you probably should use `FnOnce`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `Fn` is also `FnMut` and every `FnMut` is also `FnOnce`.

The general priority is:

- For **expecting** a type, like in function parameters or generics: `FnOnce` > `FnMut` > `Fn`. Meaning, always use `FnOnce` as it accepts all closures. Only reduce to one of the other types if your function requires it.
- For **providing** a type, like function return types: `Fn` > `FnMut` > `FnOnce`. If you return a function type, you want it to be compatible with as many usecases as possible, and `Fn` can be used as a parameter for all function types. Only change if your usecase requires it.

Here is the matrix that shows which variable type can be passed into a function that expects a certain parameter type:

| Variable type | as `FnOnce` parameter | as `FnMut` parameter | as `Fn` parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `FnOnce` | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ |
| `FnMut` | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |
| `Fn` | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |

So as you can see, a variable of type `Fn` can be passed into all functions, and a function expecting an `FnOnce` parameter can receive all variable types. So choose those whenever possible.

Like so:

```rust
fn return_fn_object() -> impl Fn() {
    || {
        println!("Hello world!");
    }
}

fn take_fn_parameter(f: impl FnOnce()) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let x = return_fn_object();
    take_fn_parameter(x);
}
```

```
Hello world!
```

---

Be aware that those three also require different ownership levels to be executed:

| Variable type | Required ownership level to execute it |
| --- | --- |
| `FnOnce` | Ownership (`self`) |
| `FnMut` | Exclusive borrow (`&mut self`) |
| `Fn` | Shared borrow (`&self`) |

So in your case, because your function is `&self`, your `postprocess` variable type must be `Fn`, and the user will not be able to provice an `FnOnce` or `FnMut` closure to your `Analyzer` struct.

If you want to be more permissive and also allow functions with side effects to be used as a `postprocess` step, then use `FnMut` and make your `pipeline` function `&mut self`.

---

> it feels weird that the compiler make decisions based on this kind of assumptions

Rust's entire ownership model is built on those three ownership types:

- Own
- Exclusive borrow
- Shared borrow

The three `Fn` types simply reflect that.

- `FnOnce` is a function that destroys itself upon getting called (= takes ownership). That means that it can include things like `drop()` calls, which can only be called once.
- `FnMut` requires an exclusive reference to be called and can therefore internally also perform exclusive actions, like modifying captured variables.
- `Fn` is always callable and requires no special ownership, but is therefore also very limited. If this is a closure, it can only read captured variables but not modify them. It can be considered side effect free. (for the most part, if you ignore interior mutability, but that's a different topic)